# cryptsetup: unknown fstype, bad password, etc. Bug? Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: boot, password, encryption, luks

I can't log in to my system. At first I had gotten the following error:

```
cryptsetup: unknown fstype, bad password or options?
```

Ubuntu spammed this at boot.

Now I can't run the Ubuntu OS installed on that drive at all. All I get is error spam for `invalid images` and `invalid image headers`.

When I use a live USB to try to access the files, I can decrypt the drive, but I still can not log in to my system normally.

Aside from the live usb, I can't access it. and even then with the live usb it's difficult; I had to download nemo and open a window with root permission to access my files.

Comment: I can't access the loading screen now, all I get is a black screen which the words invalid image, failed to load image, failed to load header pop up.

Comment: // , Can you try reformatting this? 

It's pretty hard to read. No capitalization, no line breaks, etc. Would you be willing to clean it up, or add some explanatory bits of code or screenshots? Also, this does not seem to have a question in it.

Comment: // , Also, NOT ONLY is this a practical, to the point question for askubuntu.com, since it solicits a specific answer to a specific problem in Ubuntu, but it is ALSO a good candidate for a bug report, in case it is a bug: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug